# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs

I am getting

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

while accessing the restful webservice created with hbase client api.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Blog</groupId>
<artifactId>Blog</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

this is the pom.xml

i've also added the following exclusion

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This is all I get on page

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/jaxrs/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.classForNameWithException(ReflectionHelper.java:236)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.getClassForName(AnnotationScannerListener.java:214)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationScannerListener.java:183)
    org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
    com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:100)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:87)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:72)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:672)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:414)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:581)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:703)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.classForNameWithException(ReflectionHelper.java:236)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.getClassForName(AnnotationScannerListener.java:214)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationScannerListener.java:183)
    org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
    com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:100)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:87)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:72)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:672)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:414)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:581)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:703)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The jar library containing the class `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`  is not in the classpath of your application .

Comment: Added the dependency. Thanks @Berger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening since JacksonJaxbJsonProvider is not part of your classpath.
You need to add following in your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)